# Extra padding outlook 2013

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

My email is looking great everywhere except Outlook 2013 + 2016. There seems to be extra padding on the top of my final table row.

Here is my code. The image has a height of 10px, it seems like the table has an extra 10px of padding to the top.

It's the pink(ish) row you can see above where the  is.

[image]

Here's my code. Any ideas?

```
 <table width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding: 0 !important;margin: 0 !important; background-color: #ed5d98;" bgcolor="#ed5d98">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table width="600" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" align="center style="width: 600px !important; mso-line-height-rule:exactly">
            <tr>
              <td width="600" valign="bottom" style="width: 600px !important;background-color: #fff mso-line-height-rule:exactly;" bgcolor="#fff">
                <img width="600" src="https://eoa-editor.s3.amazonaws.com/f90c5762a5514d4fa25ece7946c98bfd37feee58%2Fframe.png" alt"" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Save your email down and open it in IE. The code you have isn't necessarily the code that gets rendered by outlook. Outlook will extrapolate what you have and add default styles and elements around what it thinks it needs to.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<table width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" style="font-size: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 0;" bgcolor="#ed5d98">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%" valign="bottom" style="font-size: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 0;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                        <img width="600" src="https://eoa-editor.s3.amazonaws.com/f90c5762a5514d4fa25ece7946c98bfd37feee58%2Fframe.png" alt"" style="display: block;">
                    </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

- added `font-size: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 0;` to `<td>`s to enforce exact line height
- added `display: block;` to `<img>` to negate extra line height
- removed a few duplicate attributes from the `<table>`s and `<td>`s

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can try.  First add border="0" to the image and you can also wrap your image in a div with an inline css height set to the image.  Additionally, you can align the image left or right (depending on layout) and also add inline margin:0px to the image.

Answer (score 0):

You have mso-line-height-rule: exactly in your style, but haven't specified a line height or font size, so Outlook is going to assume something like 15px. Try adding font-size: 0; line-height: 1px; to your TD style. That usually does the trick for Outlook 2013.